# How to disable Helm's yes/no/save dialog

Tags: helm

I'm using Helm, but want to use the original Emacs dialog instead of Helm's version when closing an unsaved file.  Turns out I prefer using the Emacs' simple `y-or-n-p` dialog.

How do I disable Helm in just that particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer:

You can use

```lisp
(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(kill-buffer . completing-read))
```

to disable helm for the `completing-read` command called by the `kill-buffer` command. In this case, by default, you get the 'long-form' version of `read-multiple-choice` (i.e. you have to fully type either 'yes' or 'no').

Or you can simply (globally) configure:

```lisp
(setq use-short-answers t)
```

in which case `read-multiple-choice` does not use `completing-read`, so that helm does not get involved in the first place.

VERY BRIEF EXPLANATION

While trying to track down why/how helm gets involved here, we find from inspecting the `kill-buffer` function, that Emacs calls the function `kill-buffer--possibly-save`, which uses the function `read-multiple-choice` for prompting when killing a modified buffer, passing

```lisp
(and (not use-short-answers)
     (not (use-dialog-box-p)))
```

as the LONG-FORM argument.

We find that when that argument is nil, the `read-multiple-choice` function ultimately uses `completing-read` so that helm gets involved.

If the argument is nil (e.g. when `use-short-answer` is non-nil), `read-multiple-choice` does not use `completing-read` so that helm does not get involved at all.

Comment: The solution was related to what you recommend.  I had to set `use-short-names` to `t` (not `nil`) and that was enough.  No need to include the `add-to-list`.  For the benefit of future readers, please update your answer and I will mark this question as resolved.

Comment: A yeah, that was a 'typo'. I have corrected the answer, and added a brief explanation about the two options for disabling helm. Indeed, when setting `use-short-answers` to a non-nil value, it is not necessary to modify the `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist`, but the first option is still relevant for users who prefer the 'long' version for `read-multiple-choice`. Thanks for the feedback and the correction!

Comment: Just for future reference: it seems this functionality stopped working for me when upgrading to Emacs 29.  What happened is that the previous way of configuring short answers was deprecated (previously you had to do `(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)`).